# Who's dunit? Reputation gone?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

This is funny: This morning tex.stackexchange displayed:

[image: Picutre showing 8,310 points]

Some minutes later 15 reputation were gone:

[image: Picture showing 8,295 points]

If more people experienced this kind of bug, or it will become a habit of tex.stackexchange, somebody should look after it. Otherwise, well, it surely did not harm.

In replay to some comments: No, there is no sign of somebody deliberately cutting reputation, there is nothing in my reps-page.

Comment: Do you have *User removed* indication on your reputation page? Or did someone un-accept one of your answers?

Comment: Either it's an unaccept or you've lost three upvotes on questions: could be the 'serial voting' script, a change of votes or as @percusse says a user removal. Not a bug: rep can go down as well as up! (Remember that none of us can see the full voting info, so unless a specific individual knows what has happens an _answer_  here is impossible.)

Comment: Do you see anything odd when you check "show removed posts" at the bottom of your [reputation page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4736/keks-dose?tab=reputation)?

Comment: @Werner No, that merely was the reason for my question: that I have no clue at all why that happened. However, if nobody else experienced that, it's ok for me.

Comment: @KeksDose: Since this was a recent occurrence, I would suggest downloading the [SE data set](http://data.stackexchange.com/help) (currently dated Mar 23, 2014/yesterday). Then wait a week or so (until next Monday, when they update it again) and download it again. Then you have 2 snapshots in time to figure out what happened. Perhaps...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was an accept / unaccept on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167365/table-error-black-band-inside-the-fields-on-toprule/167386#167386) answer of yours. You must have opened the page just between those 2 events in order to see your rep being 8,310:

[image]